# Refresh Fragment from other activity when Dialog fragment is dismissed

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to achieve this?

Okay I have this process
On Index Activity, when I click the side nav Profile, it will call Fragment     (Profile) thru Fragment Transaction

```
  if (id == R.id.nav_profile){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit,R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit);
        transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, new Profile(), "ProfileFragment");
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Now I'm on the Profile Fragment:

[image: Profile Page]

When I click "Apply for Developer" button, it will call DevRegistration activity by Intent

```
  case 1:
                    btnBeDeveloper.setText("Apply for Developer");
                    btnBeDeveloper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent index = new Intent(getActivity(), DevRegistration.class);
                            startActivity(index);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
```

**Step 3:**  
On DevRegistration after I click Register, it will display a dialog fragment

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            df_SuccessDevRegistration dialogFragment = new df_SuccessDevRegistration();
            dialogFragment.show(fm, "Dev Register.");
```

Now this is my Dialog Fragment code:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_success_developer_registration, container, false);

    btnDevGoProfile = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDevGoProfile);

    btnDevGoProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Now my problem is, when I press the button on the dialog fragment, it should refresh my profile fragment. how to achieve that? I tried detach attach but my app just crashed and for null exception.

```
public class Profile extends Fragment {


TextView txvStudID, txvStudUsername, txvStudEmail, txvStudBday,txvProfileName;
CollapsingToolbarLayout ctlName;
ImageView imvProfilePic;
Button btnBeDeveloper;
View rootView;
String picURL;
FragmentTransaction ft;  Fragment currentFragment;
/** Recycler View**/

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profile_toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }
    });

    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    txvStudID = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txvStudID);
    txvStudUsername = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txvStudUsername);
    txvStudEmail = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txvStudEmail);
    txvStudBday = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txvStudBday);
    txvProfileName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txvProfileName);
    ctlName = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ctlName);
    imvProfilePic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imvProfilePic);
    btnBeDeveloper = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnBeDeveloper);

    checkLevelOfAccess();

    /** get user's data **/
    getCurrentUserData(DataClass.currentEnteredUsername);

    return rootView;
}

public void checkLevelOfAccess()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String acctID = preferences.getString("acctID", "DEFAULT");

    switch (checkLevelOfAccess(acctID)) {


        // if the level of access is developer
        case 1:
            btnBeDeveloper.setText("Developer Console");
            btnBeDeveloper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent index = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadApp.class);
                    startActivity(index);
                }
            });
            break;


        // else if the level of access is not a developer
        case 0:

            switch (checkIfRegistered(acctID))
            {
                //already apply
                case 0:
                    btnBeDeveloper.setText("Cancel Developer Request");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    btnBeDeveloper.setText("Apply for Developer");
                    btnBeDeveloper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent index = new Intent(getActivity(), DevRegistration.class);
                            startActivityForResult(index, 10001);
                        }
                    });
                    break;


            }

    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == 10001) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK))
    {
        System.out.println("IM HERE NA!!!");
        checkLevelOfAccess();
    }

}

public void getCurrentUserData(String currentUser) {

    try {
        String accountURL = DataClass.localAddress + "android_php/account.php";
        URL url = new URL(accountURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int x = 0; x < parentArray.length(); x++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(x);

            if (finalObject.getString("username").equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser) || finalObject.getString("studID").equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser)
                    || finalObject.getString("email").equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser)) {


                txvStudID.setText(finalObject.getString("studID"));
                txvStudUsername.setText(finalObject.getString("username"));
                txvStudEmail.setText(finalObject.getString("email"));
                txvStudBday.setText(convertDate(finalObject.getString("bday")));
                ctlName.setTitle(finalObject.getString("name"));
                txvProfileName.setText(finalObject.getString("name"));

                //set Profile Picture
                picURL =   DataClass.localAddress + finalObject.getString("pic");
                LoadImageFromURL loadImage = new LoadImageFromURL();
                loadImage.execute();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public String convertDate(String date) throws ParseException {
    String strCurrentDate = date;
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

    Date parseDate = inputFormat.parse(strCurrentDate);
    String converted = outputFormat.format(parseDate);
    return converted;
}

public class LoadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            InputStream is = new URL(picURL).openConnection().getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            GetCircleBitmap gcb = new GetCircleBitmap();
            Bitmap b = gcb.GetCircleBitmap(bitMap);
            return b;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imvProfilePic.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}


public int checkLevelOfAccess(String data)
{
    try {
        String accountURL =  DataClass.localAddress + "android_php/account.php";
        URL url = new URL(accountURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int x = 0; x < parentArray.length(); x++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(x);

            // true
            if (finalObject.getString("acctid").equalsIgnoreCase(data) && finalObject.getString("acctlofa").equals("1"))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (finalObject.getString("acctid").equalsIgnoreCase(data) && finalObject.getString("acctlofa").equals("0"))
            {
                return 0;
            }


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 2;
}

/** Check if the user already applied to become a developer **/
public int checkIfRegistered(String data) {
    try {
        String accountURL =  DataClass.localAddress + "android_php/developer_account.php";
        URL url = new URL(accountURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";


        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        String finalJson = buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
        JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int x = 0; x < parentArray.length(); x++) {
            JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(x);

            // pending application
            if (finalObject.getString("acctID").equalsIgnoreCase(data) && finalObject.getString("devStatus").equals("0"))
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

}

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't go immediately back to the profile fragment? For example, should the profile permanently be updated if, say, the user quits your app and starts it again a week later? If so, this suggests using some kind of permanent storage to "communicate" between the dialog and the fragment.

Comment: Actually what i am changing here is the button text, but it is based on my database, so it changes even after registering, i will close the app, the next time i open again the app the user wont have access to dev registration anymore, my only problem is that, when i register then i dismiss the dialog fragment, the profile page isnt refreshing unless i close the profile fragment then i open it again.

Comment: What method does the "fragment refresh"? Is this all in `onCreateView()`? It sounds like you need to find the correct life-cycle callback method to use for "refreshing" the fragment. Take a closer look at the fragment life-cycle to help you figure this out. If you are indeed doing everything in `onCreateView()`, you might need to move the "refresh" logic to `onResume()` instead.

Comment: i dont have yet the refresh method for the fragment, that's what i need.. on how and where should i refresh the fragment

Comment: You said that " the profile page isnt refreshing unless i close the profile fragment then i open it again". This makes it sound like you are "refreshing" somehow.

Comment: yes, because it creates the profile fragment again, so sorry im a beginner in android.. anyway what i want to say is this, when i press the back button of my profile fragment, it will   getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); then when i select it again on my sidenav,, it will just display again using the code on my question (fragmenttransaction)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138378/discussion-between-paul-john-pulumbarit-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: Whatever you are doing when the fragment is created, either in `onCreate()` or in `onCreateView()`, to display the correct data needs to be done somewhere else in the fragment's lifecycle, probably in `onResume()`.

Comment: I can be more specific if you show some code from the profile fragment.

Comment: check updated question @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Is `checkLevelOfAccess()` where you show the data depending on what the user does on the registration screen? If so override `onResume()` and call it there instead of in `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'dd suggest you using intents between activity call, and StartForRsults().

Then when your activity resume using `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)` you'll be able to check if the user correctly registered (and not cancelled registration) through a boolead in the intent.

Then, set a global variable "refreshProfile", and make it true when your activity resume with the correct intent saying user registered. Override `public void onPostResume()`, use a if statement to check wether or not you need to refresh the profile. If yes, do so then make the variable false. if not, do nothing.

Doing so will prevent you from updating your profileFragment when activity is resuming wich can cause some crash sometimes ("IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState") because you are updating the UI at the wrong moment.

Other option consists into changing the dialogFragment, setting a custom function to refresh your activity.

```
build.setPositiveButton(positiveButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    /*refresh profile here
                     with instruction like getActivity().refresh();
                     where refresh is your activity public function to refresh profile.
                     */
                }
            });
```

However, i dislike that way because your profile will wait user to confirm before being updated. I find it more clearer and elegant to have profile updated THEN prevent the user everything went fine. But personnal opinion here.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I have a problem, the problem is when i use FragmentTransaction to refresh my fragment, it returns an error; java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.support.v4.app.Fragment.mContainerId' on a null object reference

Can you help me on how to properly refresh my fragment? Should I use fragment transaction?

Comment: You don't need fragmentTransaction to do that. I'm almost sure that's not even efficient. implements the refresh method in your fragment (updating views and all) and call that method through your activity. So if you want refresh from your dialog, call order are dialog-->refresh(activity) -->refresh(profile), because your fragments are not linked to each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your fragment that you need to refresh create and register a [broadcast receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).
2. When you want to refresh the fragment (in your case when clicking the button on the dialog fragment) send a [broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html) which will be caught by your broadcast receiver on the profile fragment.

This will also make sure that the solution is not too tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result back to the activity which contains the profile data. This can be done in several ways. In this case, I assume you want the profile to remain changed permanently. For example if the user quits the app and starts it again a week later, the changes should persist to the profile screen. This suggests that you need the data to be stored permanently. For small amounts of data, such as a boolean flag or a String, you can use SharedPreferences. For more complex data, use a SQLite database or a flat file. Now the dialog just saves the data to the chosen medium and the profile fragment loads the data in `onCreate()`.